All model state validation errors localization
I'm developing a web API in .NET 6 and I'm faced with the problem of localizing model validation error messages that the framework generates. This includes both attribute-based validation, for example: [Required] - Field is required, and JSON model validation, for example: "Failed to read the request form. Request body too large."
I was able to localize the messages for standard attributes by setting up a .resx resource file and defining a LocalizedValidationMetadataProvider:
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new LocalizedValidationMetadataProvider());
});

But what about the messages that occur during JSON validation errors? What are the ways to localize it?
I suppose it is possible to set up the resource file so that the default message is the key and the value is the custom message, but this seems like a very bad approach.
I want to use the built-in Json formatting features so are there any localization options without creating a custom JsonFormatter?

I think that localization is not a JsonFormatter responsibility. You may need custom middleware, which handle errors and localize them somehow.
